# setting up and limiting access to specific fields in a record

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, access

We have 3 different groups of people who are adding data to a table or group of tables.  We need to restrict viewing of the data at the field level for 2 groups of people.  We also have a need to create forms from much of the data within the tables.  We also need to create a report for the 3rd group with the data that has been updated by the other two groups.

The security needs to be tight.

We are using SharePoint Online (365).

I am  looking for suggestions on the best way to set this up that will also be easy to manage.

I am not technically that strong, however we have folks who understand these "in's and out's".

The goal is for the cross functional team to have access to the data that they need, while ensuring that they don't have access to other data.  We are also looking to create forms with data from these tables, so that we don't have the manual entry that is currently the case.

Different problem, but connected is that it would be great if once a form was populated that we could attach and e-mail to a different person.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not have column level security, or view level security, OOTB, but there are third party tools out there that offer this functionality.  I've used SharePoint Boost's tool for this in a on-prem environment, i'm not sure what is out there for online.

Comment: Thank you for this.